# How to use Kendo UI Color Scheme on basic HTML elements?

Tags: html, css, asp.net, kendo-ui

I am fairly new to Front-end work. I am brand new to Kendo UI and Front-end Framework Development.

I have installed the Telerik Kendo UI styling tools for ASP.NET Core and created a new project. I am tweaking the base project to test it out. I even have created a custom theme with their online tool. The Kendo UI elements that are built in now use the theme I created and imported, so I know it is properly referenced in the project.

I am trying to figure out how to apply the theme styling (colors, fonts, etc.) to arbitrary HTML elements. For instance, the base project has a `kendo-button` element in the `navbar-header` div. I don't like the default `a` styling and would prefer to just put an `<h1>` element up there with no link (there is already a home button). How do I apply the Kendo Primary or Secondary Theme Color to an element like this? Or is there a plain text Kendo-UI element (like the `kendo-button`) that I am missing?

I have looked through documentation, and I have searched this site and many more. Google only returns various Telerik product results for creating the themes or how-to pages that don't address my question.